# Spring Boot Event Listener to create HashMap at application start up

Tags: spring-boot, event-listener

I have information of clients stored inside mongo db. I want to use a simple mechanism wherein I could get all the details of the clients in a HashMap at application start, so that I don't have to go to DB.
For this I was thinking of using a spring boot event listener.
But I am not able to figure out how to connect the dots for implementation.

Right Now I am thinking of simple HashMap approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement  `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner` in your spring bean. These interfaces one `run` method to override and it will execute just before `SpringApplication.run(…​)` complete.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ExampleRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-----------------checking output");

    }

}
```

output:
`2021-12-08 20:30:59.079  INFO 69065 --- [           main]  o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080  (http) with context path '' 2021-12-08 20:30:59.093  INFO 69065 --- [           main]  com.upbytes.example.ExampleApplication   : Started ExampleApplication in  2.392 seconds (JVM running for 2.849) -----------------checking output`